# Assign External/Public IPs to VMs in OpenNebula (Open vSwitch)

Tags: networking, virtualization, opennebula

I've read multiple posts asking the same question, on KVM and open nebula forums and in general virtualization ones but have only found partial or bogus answers.

Some Info:

- **Objective: Be able to rent VPSs deployed on O.N.**
- Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed a few days ago, updated
- ON is in a single host config (front-end & host are one)
- I've got a /29 IP block, would like to use those IPs on VMs

Here's what I've gathered (and attempted) so far:

[Based on the OpenNebula docs](http://docs.opennebula.org/5.7/deployment/open_cloud_networking_setup/openvswitch.html#defining-an-open-vswitch-network) I've setup the OVS bridge like so:

```
# Create bridge and add port
ovs-vsctl add-br ovsbr0
ovs-vsctl add-port ovsbr0 enp3s0

# Change external IP address from port to bridge
ip addr flush dev enp3s0
ip addr add xxx.xxx.110.50/29 dev ovsbr0
ip link set ovsbr0 up
ip route add default via xxx.xxx.110.49 dev ovsbr0
```

This leaves me with access to the internet alright, and the bridge setup [just like their example](http://docs.opennebula.org/5.7/deployment/open_cloud_networking_setup/node.html#id5):

```
dba23490-cd85-40f4-a3b5-dfe9c4e2e60a
    Bridge "ovsbr0"
        Port "enp3s0"
            Interface "enp3s0"
        Port "ovsbr0"
            Interface "ovsbr0"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.9.2"
```

cool! Well, this is the part where I'm lost. What now? **how do I add this to Open Nebula so my new VMs have external IPs?**

**In case I'm failing hard, what other way could I do this?**

Some other info that might be useful:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master ovs-system state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:62:f9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:62:f9:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c6:e4:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c6:e4:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:1d:97:0a:8e:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: ovsbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:62:f9:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.110.50/29 scope global ovsbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
# ip route
default via xxx.xxx.110.49 dev ovsbr0
xxx.xxx.110.48/29 dev ovsbr0 proto kernel scope link src xxx.xxx.110.50
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Thanks in advance.
[Link to my OpenNebula forums post](https://forum.opennebula.org/t/assign-public-external-ip-to-vms-using-open-vswitch-bridge/6898)

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working!

Here's my Virtual Network template:

```
BRIDGE = "ovsbr0"
BRIDGE_TYPE = "openvswitch"
DESCRIPTION = "Network with public IPs"
DNS = "8.8.8.8"
GATEWAY = "xxx.xxx.110.49"
OUTER_VLAN_ID = ""
PHYDEV = ""
SECURITY_GROUPS = "0"
VLAN = "YES"
VLAN_ID = ""
VN_MAD = "ovswitch"

# optional QoS params

INBOUND_AVG_BW = "5785"
INBOUND_PEAK_BW = "9000"
INBOUND_PEAK_KB = "20000"
OUTBOUND_AVG_BW = "4200"
OUTBOUND_PEAK_BW = "9000"
OUTBOUND_PEAK_KB = "20000"
```

Turns out this info isn't in the *Deployment* guide but in the [Operation guide](http://docs.opennebula.org/5.7/operation) where you can find vnet templates.

Example given by them:

```
# Configuration attributes (OpenvSwitch driver)
NAME        = "Public"
DESCRIPTION = "Network with public IPs"

BRIDGE  = "br1"
VLAN    = "YES"
VLAN_ID = 12

DNS           = "8.8.8.8"
GATEWAY       = "130.56.23.1"
LOAD_BALANCER = 130.56.23.2

AR=[ TYPE = "IP4", IP = "130.56.23.2", SIZE = "1"]
AR=[ TYPE = "IP4", IP = "130.56.23.34", SIZE = "1"]
AR=[ TYPE = "IP4", IP = "130.56.23.24", SIZE = "1"]
AR=[ TYPE = "IP4", IP = "130.56.23.17", MAC= "50:20:20:20:20:21", SIZE = "1"]
AR=[ TYPE = "IP4", IP = "130.56.23.12", SIZE = "1"]
```